# How Can I Install Webpack Offline?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a problem with webpack! I want to know if there is a way that I can install it offline or a way to install all npm packages offline, pre-downloaded.

I have my PC at home without internet connection. I am able to reach an internet café with my phone and download all my stuff. I also have Termux installed along with NPM, Node.js, and Python, but it is useless in this case and can't run `npm i webpack`. It just throws errors that is related to internet connection (as mine is so bad) and "Permission Denied" errors since I don't have a rooted phone.

Searching the internet, I found that `npm pack` will have everything packaged and installable offline (incase I had `"bundledDependencies": true`.) I attended CS50 before and had access to their online IDE where NPM is pre-installed. I have packaged everything and I received a `something-1.0.0.tgz` file weighting about 160MB. I have run `npm i something-1.0.0.tgz` on my offline PC and it stuck at `sill idealTree buildDeps`. `npm rebuild` does not work either.

I want to know if I can download any npm package as it is online and run `npm i webpack.tgz`, for example, and have with all it's dependencies installed. Downloading it from Github needs more dependencies online.

And not to forget, I want to do the same with react, react-dom, react-script, react-three/fiber, react-three/drei,  and any other npm package I may need in the future!

Comment: Trust me on this, you can't be an offline developer. Find a way to have an internet on your PC (maybe USB wi fi router and than use your phone as hot spot)